# pnpm install did nothing but show Scope: all 7 workspace projects

Tags: pnpm

`pnpm install` did nothing but show `Scope: all 7 workspace projects`.

```sh
xxxxxxxxx xxxxx %pnpm install
Scope: all 7 workspace projects
xxxxxxxxx xxxxx %pnpm --version
6.24.2
```

device:
using macOS Big Sur

I will be very grateful if anyone answers me.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. Just put all workspaces in `pnpm-workspace.yaml`